# using field selected in outer part of query as parameter for sub query

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, null, correlated-subquery

How can I use a field selected in the outer part of a query as a parameter for the subquery?  I thought this was more or less it but obviously not as is should return a couple of rows

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM table1 t1
WHERE status = 1
AND (
      SELECT ref from table2 where altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1,4)
    ) != NULL
```

UPDATE
Thanks for all the answers so far.  I should say though, using EXIST would return true all the time, as the row in the sub query will exist, just not necessarily with a value in 'altref', so I amended the EXISTS to include the is not null on the alt ref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're checking against `null` with the [in]eqaulity operator. `Null` isn't a value - it's the lack thereof - and thus, any value comparison against it (e.g., `=`, `!=`, `>`, etc) would return "unknown" (which isn't true, so any row returning evaluating to it won't be returned).

Instead, you should use the `IS` operator:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM table1 t1
WHERE status = 1
AND (
      SELECT ref from table2 where altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1,4)
    ) IS NOT NULL
-- Here^
```

It's worth noting, BTW, that the `exists` operator may be a tad more elegant:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  status = 1 AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   table2
               WHERE  altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ref from table2 where altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1,4)
    ) as table2 on table2.altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1,4)
WHERE status = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `!= NULL`.  This will always fail the filtering in the `WHERE` clause (the result is going to be `NULL` which is never true).

I think you want:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM table1 t1
WHERE status = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 from table2 t2 where t2.altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1, 4));
```

If `t2.ref` could be `NULL`, then the appropriate version is:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM table1 t1
WHERE status = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table2 t2 
              WHERE t2.altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1, 4) AND t2.ref IS NOT NULL
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `EXISTS`

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM table1 t1
WHERE status = 1
AND exists (
           SELECT ref from table2 where altref = SUBSTR(t1.f2, 1,4)
           )
```